# How to install and configure Intel C++ Compiler for Mathematica correctly?

Tags: compile, interoperability, windows, ccompilerdriver

I wish to try the trial version of the latest Intel C++ Compiler for Windows with *Mathematica*. I have downloaded the current version of [Intel® C++ Composer XE 2011 for Windows](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-evaluation-center/#compilers) and installed only the "Intel C++ Compiler" component from this package. But *Mathematica* does not recognize it:

```
In[1]:= Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
CCompilers[]

Out[2]= {}
```

How to configure *Mathematica* to use the Intel C++ Compiler?

Comment: Make sure you have installed the 64 bit tools for Visual studio (if you are on a 64 bit system). You did install visual studio right?

Comment: @Ajasja At least when using the Microsoft compiler, it's not strictly necessary to install Visual Studio.  The [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) with the command line compiler will suffice.  But the Intel compiler I have never used on Windows.

Comment: @Ajasja I use 32 bit Windows XP. I have not installed Visual Studio. Is it strictly necessary?

Comment: Yes, for the Intel compiler it is strictly necessary. It works with the Express edition as well, at least I think so.

Comment: @Ajasja Well, now I am downloading and installing [Visual C++ 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express).

Comment: @Ajasja The installation of Visual C++ 2010 Express has finished but after restarting the computer I still have no Intel compiler listed in `CCompilers[]` output even after setting ``$CCompiler = {"Compiler" -> CCompilerDriver`IntelCompiler`IntelCompiler}``. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your Mathematica, what does Environment["ICPP_COMPILER11"] return?

Comment: @jfklein It returns `$Failed` (I have already installed Visual C++ 2010 Express).

Comment: This Intel version 12 is not supported, and that's why CCompilerDriver is not automatically detecting your Intel compiler.  Until I have a chance to look into this, you could go into AddOns/Applications/CCompilerDriver/IntelCompilerWindows.m and replace ICPP_COMPILER11 with ICPP_COMPILER12.  This may work only superficially, but it would be the fastest thing for you to try.

Comment: As @jfklein mentioned the latest supported compiler is 11.1 (see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CCompilerDriver/tutorial/SpecificCompilers.html)). Perhaps you could define ICPP_COMPILER11 and point it to ICPP_COMPILER12. Otherwise it's probably possible to set the compiler manually (see Setting a Different Compiler in the previous link)

Comment: @jfklein It works, thank you. @Ajasja After defining ``$CCompiler = {"Compiler"->CCompilerDriver`IntelCompiler`IntelCompiler,"CompilerInstallation"->"C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Composer XE 2011 SP1\\"};`` now `DefaultCCompiler[]` returns ``CCompilerDriver`IntelCompiler`IntelCompiler``.

Comment: @alexey Does defining `$CCompiler` work on it's own or do you have to change `IntelCompilerWindows.m` as well?

Comment: @Ajasja Without changing `IntelCompilerWindows.m` `CCompilers[]` does not list `IntelCompiler`. I have taken the value for `$CCompiler` from the list returned by `CCompilers[]` after changing `IntelCompilerWindows.m` .

Comment: CCompilers[] only lists compilers that are seen to be valid installations.  CCompilers[Full] will list all compilers supported on that $SystemID.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mathematica 8 automatically detects Intel version 11, but not Intel version 12 which was released later.

In order to use the Intel 12 compiler, you'll need to set [$CCompiler](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CCompilerDriver/ref/%24CCompiler.html) to point CCompilerDriver to where you've installed the Intel compiler:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
$CCompiler = {"Compiler" -> 
    CCompilerDriver`IntelCompiler`IntelCompiler, 
   "CompilerInstallation" -> "E:\\IntelCompiler"};
```

You can put this in a kernel initialization file, such as $UserBaseDirectory/Kernel/init.m so you don't need to evaluate it every time you start Mathematica.

Comment: This should now Just Work in Mathematica 9.