# Problem setting up C compiler on a Mac

Tags: mac-os-x, ccompilerdriver

This is a follow up to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6897/what-compilers-are-suitable-for-compilationtarget-c) question. I am using Mma 10 on a MacBook-Pro with OS-X Mavericks. After reading the documentation under CCompilerDriver/tutorial/SpecificCompilers I did the following:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
CCompilers[]
```

[image]

The documentations says they are the compilers that *are found on my machine* and that the CCompilerDriver package is automatically called when using  CompilationTarget->"C" inside Compile. However, I can't get Compile working with CompilationTarget->"C". I also tried the Basic example in the documentation for CreateLibrary, and $Failed was returned. That means a suitable compiler could not be found. The documentation at CCompilerDriver/tutorial/SpecificCompilers also says, " Many Unix-type operating systems such as Linux or Mac OS X come with GCC already installed. If it is not present, then it can be added with a relatively simple configuration step." Can you help me with that *simple configuration step*?

Comment: What does `FileNames["/usr/bin/clang"]` give?  It should give a result, since `CCompilers[]` is supposed to only list things that are actually installed.

Comment: Very likely you need to install Xcode. unless things changed with Mavericks, OSX has a compiler available but not installed by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To long for comment,

Hit Command+Shift+G from the OS X desktop

A Commandline will open,

enter /user/bin and hit open

[image]

There will open a new window, containing a long list, search for clang:

[image]

If clang or others are NOT on this list, most likely you have to install "Command Line Tools" see [here](http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html) (or ask Google ...).

Always check with friends when installing new Software!

Good Luck!

Comment: After doing that I see the clang file. Then I wrote the simple Compile function acl suggested below. It compiled without problem and it works. The problem is solved!

Answer (score 2):

Very likely you need to install Xcode. Unless things changed with Mavericks, OSX has a compiler available but not installed by default

As Brett Champion mentioned, try FileNames["/usr/bin/clang"] 
If this returns a file, then clang (A compiler) is installed, and likely should work.

Comment: FileNames["/usr/bin/clang"] returns {/usr/bin/clang}. I downloaded and installed Xcode, registered with Apple as an xCode developer. I can open the xCode IDE, but there may be some other steps needed to get it working. Anyway, I thought xCode is an objective-C compiler. From what I read it sounds like you can't write a C program for OSX. It seems you have to write an objective-C program instead. However, Compile in Mathematica doesn't allow for CompilationTarget->"objective C". So what do I do next?

Comment: @TedErsek You can most certainly write C programs for OSX (or any other language for which you have a compiler). XCode is an IDE, which is meant to help with writing code. It's focussed on objective C and C, but supports other languages. Now, you seem to have clang installed in the usual place, so there is some misconfiguration in mma itself. Does `Compile[{{z, _Real, 1}}, Sin[z], CompilationTarget -> "C"]` also return `$Failed`?

Comment: I evaluated that simple example. It compiles without problem, and it works. The problem is solved.