# How can I set up Compile[] correctly on my Windows 11? I keep on getting an error that I have no compilers installed (but I do)

Tags: compile, c

I'm trying to use Mathematica's `Compile[]` function to speed up some of my computations:

```
Compile[<some_code>, CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

However, whenever I try to do so, I get the following error:

```
CCompilerDriver`CreateLibrary::nocomp: A C compiler cannot be found on your system. Please consult the documentation to learn how to set up suitable compilers.
```

When I execute the following code:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
CCompilers[]
```

I get

```
{}
```

And when I execute

```
CCompilers[Full]
```

I get

```
{{"Name" -> "Intel Compiler", 
"Compiler" -> CCompilerDriver`IntelCompiler`IntelCompiler, 
"CompilerInstallation" -> None, 
"CompilerName" -> Automatic}, {"Name" -> "Generic C Compiler", 
"Compiler" -> CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`GenericCCompiler, 
"CompilerInstallation" -> None, "CompilerName" -> Automatic}}
```

---

I am using Mathematica 11 and Windows 11. What I've tried so far:

- Installed `gcc` on my computer and configured the `PATH` correctly. When I type `gcc` on the command line, I get the expected output.
- Installed Visual Studio 2022 C++ development tools.
- Installed Visual Studio 2022 Build Tools for C/C++ development.
- Read the documentations (both the official one and the one linked below).

What more can I do?

Comment: maybe useful: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5593/9490

Comment: You have to tell Mathematica where your compiler is.  I use the MinGW compiler so after the Needs command I execute `$CCompiler = {"Compiler" -> 
    CCompilerDriver`MinGWCompiler`MinGWCompiler, 
   "CompilerInstallation" -> 
    "C:\\Program Files\\CodeBlocks\\MinGW\\bin"};
` which give the location of the MinGW c-compiler bin file on my machine.

Comment: Probably the first link should solve it. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41682/c-compilation-not-working-with-visual-studio-2013 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6897/what-compilers-are-suitable-for-compilationtarget-c